# Mitigating http attacks away from Express

Tags: http, node.js

I'm serving a few static files using Express and Node.JS, what can I do to protect against http floods such as POST attacks and GET attacks?

Answer (score 2):

All requests are pre-catched with app.use and injected in a middleware function. This is used before request beeing followed to express.static or app.rest (the req object), and one more time before beeing responded to client (the res object). You can alterate req, res, and optionnally use the callback function (here named *next*). Here it is the trick. If your middleware function never call the *next()* callback, the request is not served. You can use a middleware, which count requests per ip per time, and serve or not the page.
Think about the list of blocked ip will grow and will slow your app. Middlewares need to be sync to intercept. Here an exemple of your needed code, based on express API doc exemple:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
util= require(util);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// a first middleware, a logger in console, just to show ip
// usefull to debug
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('%s %s from %s , proxy: %s', req.method, req.url, req.ip, util.inspect(req.ips));
  next();
});

// a second middleware, what u need
app.use(filterUrReq);

app.get("blah", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.url + " well served to " + req.ip)
});

app.listen(8080);

// here the middleware function, it filters by ip, if ip is clean, call next callback.
function filterUrReq (req, res, next) {

    if (req.ip == "15.89.111.111") {
        console.log('i dont want to serve this IP, dont call next');
    } else {
        console.log('ok clean ip, go to next app.use');
        next();
    }

}
```

here the good practices for expressJS. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use .
Maybe your question should be in stackoverflow, or maybe you need something more global like **[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/)**, take a look about jails problematics.